# How to filter DataGridView rows using a predicate?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<T>` which is bound to a DataGridView like this:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = list;
myDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

I want to filter the rows that are displayed using a predicate. How do I achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: You can write some other logic to filter the perticular row in the datagrid..

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution be following:

```
Func<T, bool> predicate = ...; // Func<T, bool> or Predicate<T>

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = list.Where(x => predicate(x));
myDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

If your predicate changes then either refresh the data source or just re-assign it using the new predicate.